# Hangman VB Not Working

Tags: vb.net

I am making a hangman game on VB. An help is appreciated

All I have is that player 1 enters a word. The program then puts it into an array, which sorts it into letters. The player 2 (on the same computer) tries to guess the  word, one letter at the time. They type in a letter and the program will go trough the array to check if there are any letter in the word. If there are it will show the letter (leaving the others blank) and leave the scoring system at 10 (I still need to put this in) If they guess wrong the letters will remain covered and it will minus 1 of the scoring system.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim myword, guess As String
    Dim mywordlen As Integer
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Console.WriteLine("Player 1, please enter a word to guess")
    myword = Console.ReadLine()
    mywordlen = myword.Length
    Dim answer(mywordlen) As Char

    For x = 0 To mywordlen - 1
        answer(x) = "_"
        While answer > 0 Then 
            Console.WriteLine("Please guess a letter")
            guess = Console.ReadLine()
            flag = False
            For x = 0 To mywordlen - 1
                If guess = myword Then {0}
                    answer(x) = guess
                    flag = True
                    Console.WriteLine("The answer is, {0}")
            Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting and on which line?

Comment: The code doesn't even compile.

Comment: Do you have any idea how this sort of system could work?? All I have is that player 1 enters a word. The program then puts it into an array, which sorts it into letters. The player 2 (on the same computer) tries to guess the  word, one letter at the time. They type in a letter and the program will go trough the array to check if there are any letter in the word. If there are it will show the letter (leaving the others blank) and leave the scoring system at 10 (I still need to put this in) If they guess wrong the letters will remain covered and it will minus 1 of the scoring system.

Comment: Check your syntax - it seems like you need to work through a few more tutorials.  You have a `While` without an `End While`, you have an `If` without an `End If`, you've constructed a comparison between a `Char()` and a number, you're redeclaring a loop variable, etc.  The Error List in the IDE will give you a specific list of all of these problems and the lines they occur on.  Programming is an extremely precise discipline - you cannot just type whatever and expect the compiler to understand what you want.  There are rules for the language syntax and ample documentation describing them.

Comment: Ok thanks. So if i add an end while and an end if that will help my problem. What code do i use for the char part. I thought as they were entering a letter then a char would work ?

Comment: It will help, yes, but your code has many problems and this question is already off-topic for several reasons (too broad, typographical errors, etc).  Stack Overflow is not a support forum or tutorial site.  What you really need is to take more time to learn the language - with simpler examples if necessary.  You should also learn to use the debugger and to understand compiler error messages - learn to look them up to see what they mean.  This will help you to focus your questions in the future.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim myword, guess As String
Dim mywordlen, x As Integer
Dim flag As Boolean
Console.WriteLine("Player 1, please enter a word to guess")
myword = Console.ReadLine()
mywordlen = myword.Length - 1
Dim answer(mywordlen), displayword(mywordlen) As Char
Dim score As Integer = 10

For x = 0 To mywordlen
    answer(x) = Mid(myword, x + 1, 1)
    displayword(x) = "_"
Next
While score > 0 
    Console.WriteLine("Please guess a letter")
    guess = Console.ReadLine()  'Assumes user only types one letter
    flag = False
    For x = 0 To mywordlen
        If guess = answer(x) Then
            displayword(x) = guess
            flag = True
        End If
    Next
    If flag Then
        If New String(displayword) = myword Then
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You won!")
            Exit While
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Correct! {0}", New String(displayword))
        End If
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect. {0}", New String(displayword))
        score -= 1
    End If
End While
Console.WriteLine("Game over. The word was {0}", myword)
```